# How to force \section{} to start new page? in latex

Tags: sectioning

I am writing a short manuscript using `\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book}`. Here is what I have

```
% Bunch of packages
\begin{document}
 \chapter{Virus}
  .
  .
   \begin{figure}[ht!]
     \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{simulation.jpg}}
     \captionof{figure}{xxx}
     \label{yy}
 \end{figure}
 % a couple more figures
 \section{stay home}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the section begins at the end of a page. Above the section line, there are two pictures almost filling up the page. It looks really odd to have section begin at the end of a page, as of now, I have tried.

1. ```
   \newpage
   \section{stay home}
   ```
2. ```
   \pagebreak
   \section{stay home}
   ```
3. ```
   \goodbreak
   \section{stay home}
   ```

after importing `needspace` package

4. ```
   \Needspace{40\baselineskip}
   \section{stay home}
   ```

None of the above methods worked. Is there some more methods that I could try?

Comment: Did you try `\clearpage`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thanks a lot. It worked like a magic!

Comment: I am wondering what "none...worked" means in the question. `\newpage` and `\pagebreak` should have basically worked; `\goodbreak` likely had no effect; and `\needspace` should have worked well in a way that it wouldn't need to be inserted manually just where needed (it could be incorporated with `\section`).

Comment: @DonaldArseneau , I was even surprised but \clearpage did the job.

Comment: What *followed* `\section`?  The immediate context is often instrumental in controlling a page break, and that's information you haven't shown.

Comment: @barbarabeeton bunch of text

Comment: The reason I asked is that an `itemize` or `enumerate` list, or a `\subsection` might well trigger a page brea, leaving a `\section` at the bottom of a page.  But that doesn't explain why `\newpage` doesn't work.  What is needed here is an actual example that demonstrates the problem "in action".

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you for your knowledge. I was assuming those figures above the section were messing up with me. I wish I could show it in video or sth but \clearpage worked. So, I am happy with it as of now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `\clearpage` just before `\section`:

```
\clearpage
\section{Why 42? Because it is the ASCII code of the character *}
```

credit to @user194703 in the comments.